# Time and Temperature to bake small fruit cakes

Tags: baking, cake, temperature

I want to bake fruit cakes in foil pans holding about 1 1/4 cups of batter. Should I use bain marie ? What temperature oven will be best and for approximately how long

Answer (score 6):

Recipes for fruitcake vary tremendously, without more information there isn't any way to say how long and at what temperature. I looked at several recipes, and none called for a bain marie, but some do recommend a pan of water below the cake to provide moist heat.

You might find this [Food Network Recipe](http://www.foodnetwork.com/recipes/moms-fruitcake-recipe.html) helpful, because it gives directions for various cake sizes, but the directions are for this particular recipe, not yours. If I were using that link as a guide, I would use a temp of about 260-265F and start testing the cakes for doneness at about 1.5 hours.

All of the fruitcake recipes I looked at use a skewer or toothpick stuck in the center to test for doneness. The cake is done when the toothpick comes out clean.

Comment: Great answer! While recipes vary as you noted, most fruitcakes work with low & slow.

Comment: Thank you for this information.......I will bake as you suggest......and thank you for the Food Network tip

Answer (score 0):

You might end up drying out a smaller cake for slow baking. Personally I crank the heat up by 10c (50f?) And just check around the 60 minute mark.. sometimes foil on the top after 60 mins to stop over browning..For sure the cake will cook quicker if it is smaller.